# What is the easiest way to render a circuit schematic embeddable in TeX from a netlist?

Tags: diagrams, circuits, engineering

What is a common schematic netlist format of an EDA tool like KiCAD or gEDA to automatically create/reverse engineer a schematic render or is it easier to use an SVG format?

For starters, I'd like something like this:
[image]

Can you suggest any good/light SW tool for this purpose?
I am new to circuit design and documentation although I am an electrical engineer I've forgotten much as I did SW testing mainly in the last decade. :( I am working on an electronic musical instrument.

Thanks/cheers friends!

Comment: The graphicx package can handle some formats (pdf and jpeg) but I can't find a complete list in the documentation.  The epsfig package adds some additional drivers.  Worst case, use a graphics editor (like Gimp) to convert formats.  You can create schematics from scratch using TikZ or circuitikz (the latter has more predefined components).

Comment: Almost forgot the svg package, which adds an SVG driver to graphicx.